# Substitute text in a formula for text from a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to substitute a specific part of a formula for the text contained in a different Cell.

The formula is:

```
=SUMIFS(Data!$C$2:$C$300000,Data!$O$2:$O$300000,"c285",Data!$G$2:$G$300000,">"&DATE(2017,1,1))
```

This formula is the same all the way down my spreadsheet although it should only be in cell O1. I want to change the part of the formula that says "c285" to match the value in the cell in each row

Is there a way to do this without me doing it manually?

The forumula can be seen in all the cells in Column O, they are all the same as they all have the same formula at the moment

[image]

Comment: Why don't you simply replace the literal string "c1" by a reference to the cell which contains the string? It isn't clear what your actual problem is.

Comment: If this is in `O1`, just do `=SUMIFS(Data!$C$2:$C$300000,Data!$O$2:$O$300000,$A1,Data!$G$2:$G$300000,">"&DATE(2017,1,1))` (assuming by "cell in row A" you mean "the value in column A of the row the formula is in")

Comment: It sounds like you could just change it to A1 with quotations, so it will be a cell reference and then drag it down.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was being stupid. Sometimes I get so stuck trying to do formulas it's more basic than you think. John Coleman's answer got it.

Answer (score 0):

Route 1:if you want to do it programmatically -> take a net language of your choice
take the cell content, search for the position of C1, change that to C +iterator
save it to the cell

Route 2: change the first few cells, delete the rest. Select all the correct cells, click on the right corner, pull down till you got all your rows auto completed
(this works for simple formulas, dates and so on. You would have to test this)

And always have a backup copy